# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to align an `Image` to the center of the `Grid` cell. The `Image` is within a `Canvas`. How do I go about doing this?

```
private void image()
{
    Image myBarCode = new Image();
    myBarCode.Width = 400;
    myBarCode.Height = 300;
    myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = Left;
    myBarCode.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/Users/mark/Desktop/resident images/Doris.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    mainCanvas1.Children.Add(myBarCode);
}
```

Comment: It seems to say that `Left` has the wrong type...

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment` expects an enum - `myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;`

Comment: @keyboardP , why you don't type this in Answer box ?

Comment: Done :) Just wanted to make sure that that was the only issue regarding the alignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) property expects an [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment.aspx) enum.

```
myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Comment: +1 for the first correct answer. Wonder how many exact clone answers it takes before people realize they're stating the exact same thing as the answer

Comment: There are always several peoples watching and possible several of them will start answering. Those usually finish at nearly same time (possible exception!). Others, who just blindly add their answers (but much later), are either need reputation (can u help me plx? plx?) or are blind =D

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Answer (score 1):

The HorizontalAlignment property takes a value of the enumeration with the same name:

```
myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

You're assigning the value of your windows/controls Left property, which is of type double.

Answer (score 0):

```
myBarCode.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```